# Where can i find info or documentation regarded to Online Advertising?

Tags: architecture

I'm trying to build an Ad system. Some time before i wanted to build a WebCrawler, and found tons of Papers and doc.

But for Ads i've not found anything useful yet. Everything is related to "CPC, CPM" and stuff like that (marketing related). Nothing "architectural" or "technical" that can help me to build it the real system, and write some code down.

Can you help me with some links or references?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on a sister site?

Comment: Don't think so. I'm looking for information related to system Architecture, coding, desing, etc. Pure Software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it doesn't talk about advertising directly, the book [Algorithms of the Intelligent Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988665) discusses several topics that I would imagine would be very valuable in setting up an advertising system - especially concerning how/where to place ads and how to target viewers (provide ad content tailored to a viewer or to a specific webpage with a certain class of viewers in mind).  These include:

- Search algorithms
- Suggestion algorithms
- Recommendation algorithms
- Clustering algorithms
- Classification algorithms
- Developing dynamic content based on users' input/behavior
- etc.

You may want to also check out [Collective Intelligence in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988312).  It discusses things like:

- Architectures for intelligent/social web,
- Extracting intelligence from tags and keywords
- Content architectures
- Detecting valuable phrases
- Recommendation engines
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is in Ruby, but the examples could be implemented in any programming language 
http://www.igvita.com/2007/01/15/svd-recommendation-system-in-ruby/